# ul and li 100% height of non-fixed parent

Tags: html, css

I am looking for the easiest way to get a `< ul >` and it's `< li >` elements to a 100% height of the `< ul >'s` parent. The parent is not fixed (and I am trying to avoid that so it is flexible on mobile devices). Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bondanr/xzadjkrx/)

Basically I want the red boxes to be 100% height of the grayish box.

Thanks!

Note: I have tried various things already, its just nothing seemed to work properly.

Comment: Can you please check this is what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/xzadjkrx/5/

Comment: Eh no a fixed area up the height. I am trying to avoid a fixed height header.

Comment: A parent container of the ul will need a fixed height declared for them to know what 100% height means. Otherwise you will need to do some fancy java script to dynamically detect the height.

Comment: When you say you want the `ul` to be *100% height of the `ul`s parent*, you mean 100% height of an unknown variable? The parent's height is dynamic?

Comment: Right, I need the unordered lists's parent to be dynamic.

Comment: Have you tried flexbox - http://jsfiddle.net/nw7wr51g/?

Comment: I think @Aleksey is correct. You should consider using flexbox. Also, you applied a `height: 100%` to the `ul`. But the browser needs to know *100% of what?* ... With flexbox you don't need to use percentage heights, but if you decide to go that way, review this first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: @Aleksey is correct with the use of flexbox for this situation. However, flexbox is still not supported well in IE, if you need that browser support.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you need to do.

1. Specify the height of the `.site-header` e.g. 40px
2. Every parent of `li` needs to be 100% heigh
3. Make the title and nav container inline

This should work

```
 h1 {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}
.site-header {
  background: rgba( 0,0,0,0.5 );
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.row {
  height: 100%;
}
.site-title {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono';
  font-weight: 100;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}
.site-nav {
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}
```